# python : list index out of range error 1

Tags: python, list, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to check if the array I'm returning is empty.

The code i'm trying is:

```
if (r.json()['negative'][0]['topic']) == "":
```

the error i'm getting is index out of range error.

I know that means there is nothing in the array, but my code is crashing because it's returning nothing.

Any Ideas?

Comment: why don't you check the len()?

Comment: How about checking for empty array by doing `len(my_list) == 0`?

Comment: Can I ask why, was my question voted down ??

So I don't do the same things next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t put it all in a single line or you lose the ability to know what exactly is going on.

```
data = r.json()
if 'negative' not in data:
    print('negative key is missing')
elif len(data['negative']) == 0:
    print('no items in the negative list')
elif 'topic' not in data['negative'][0]:
    print('topic is missing')
elif data['negative'][0]['topic'] == '':
    print('topic is empty')
else:
    # now you can access it safely
    print(data['negative'][0]['topic'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access first element from an empty array r.json()['negative'] which is causing your code to fail.

Check if "negative" key is not empty array after that you can check your condition.

```
if (r.json()['negative']:
    if (r.json()['negative'][0]['topic']) == "":
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are going 3 deep into a set of dictionary in a list in a dictionary- you will almost certainly need to check the length of each container (or check that the key is in the dictionary) as suggested by others, or it is considered more pythonic by some to just capture the exception and move on :

```
try:
    if (r.json()['negative'][0]['topic']) == "":
        # do stuff
except IndexError:
       # do other stuff
```

This is the `It is better to ask forgiveness than to ask permission` principle which is commonly used.